# Google Maps API limits with Fusion Tables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I was interested in using google maps API with quite big KML imported as fusion table. I used the basic example from google tutorials on how to use fusion table as a layer in a map, and after ~8 hours of me just trying out stuff the API started to throw an error, that 25.000 map loads limit have been reached. Google developer console doesn't say it's even close hitting any limit. Does anybody know if KML complexity or size can affect API limits? Or maybe I've some potential loops in the code? Or generally what could cause the problem? Here is what I did:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        console.log('asdf');
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.11786991747952, 17.001362352071737),
            zoom: 18,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            map: map,
            heatmap: {
                enabled: false
            },
            query: {
                select: "col13",
                from: "<TABLE>",
                where: ""
            },
            options: {
                styleId: 2,
                templateId: 2
            },
            styles: [{
                where: 'col3 \x3d \x27VALUE\x27',
                polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor: '#0000FF'
                }
            }]
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your HTML as well?

Comment: I'm not sure how would that help, It's really basic, just the body and a div with id 'googft-mapCanvas'. Nothing fancy.